# Compute the Group of Automorphisms of the Abelian Group $\mathbb{Q}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rational-numbers, automorphism-group

> Compute explicitly the group of automorphisms $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}^n)$ of the abelian group $\mathbb{Q}^n=\mathbb{Q}\times ...\times \mathbb{Q}$.

This task is from on an old exam. As far as I know, for $n=1$ we have $\phi(q)=q\cdot\phi(1) = q\cdot a$ for any $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and some $a\in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence, I presume that in the general case we have $$\phi(q_1,q_2,...,q_n)=(q_1,...,q_n) \cdot \phi(1,...,1)$$ So any automorphism would be determined by how it maps $$\phi(1,...,1)=\phi(1,0,...,0)~+~...~+~\phi(0,...,0,1)$$ i.e. how it maps the basis elements. What can we conclude? Is there any meaningful group isomorphic to $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}^n)$? How would I determine this?
I'm not sure if I understand what the task is actually asking for.

Comment: This question is non-sensical. The answeris $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$, but I have no idea how they expect you to 'describe that explicitly'.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: that's pretty explicit, isn't it?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I guess it depends on your definition. It's a pretty poorly-worded question imo.

Comment: Take an endomorphism $\Bbb{Q^n\to Q^n}$, from how it acts on the basis you get a matrix $\in M_n(\Bbb{Q})$, this is a ring, the automorphisms are those with a multiplicative inverse: $GL_n(\Bbb{Q})$, the main theorem is that $GL_n(k) = \{ A\in M_n(k), \det(A)\ne 0\}$.

Comment: I agree that the question makes no sense. It is not hard to prove that ${\rm Aut}({\mathbb Q}^n) \cong {\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Q})$, but this is a conceptual proof, and there is no computation involved at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$. Then we have
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(V)\cong GL(V),
$$
or in other words,
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(K^n)\cong GL_n(K).
$$
Here $K=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Do you have any hint on how this could have been 'computed explicitly'? Or would this simply amount to the proof of the statements in your answer?

Comment: An isomorphism of vector spaces automatically gives an isomorphism of the underlying abelian groups. You have seen already the proof for vector spaces in linear algebra, I suppose. The automorphisms of a vector space form a group, the so called general linear group $GL(V)$. Of course, we can explicitly write down the elements of $GL_n(\Bbb Q)$.

Comment: I have not seen this in linear algebra yet (at least not with proof) but I will look into it. I'm still sceptical though whether this was what the instructor expected.